# log4j2 java classes do not load application.properties entries with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am using log4j2(log4j-core and log4j-api) with Spring boot 2.2.0.RELEASE. I want to masking sensitive data inmy json payload in the logs. I have written a custom LogMaskingConverter which extends LogEventPatternConverter.

```
@Plugin(name = "LogMaskingConverter", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({ "spi", "trscId" })
@Configuration
public class LogMaskingConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {
    @Value("${maskingFields}")
    private String maskingFields;

    protected LogMaskingConverter(String name, String style) {
        super(name, style);
    }

    public static LogMaskingConverter newInstance(String[] options) {
        return new LogMaskingConverter("spi", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder outputMessage) {
        ........
    }
    private String mask(String message) {
       ....
     }
```

The problem is that the maskingFields does not get loaded from the application properties file.I read that log4j2 gets loaded before spring boot. Hence I have renamed my xml to log4j2-spring.xml so that spring boot is the first to intialise and load all the properties before it gets read via LogMaskingConverter.

Also below are my pom.xml dependencies related to log4j2

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

To summarise below code does not fetch any values:

```
@Value("${maskingFields}")
private String maskingFields;
```

Comment: Did you find answer for this? if yes please submit. I also facing the same issue here.